# EXC Bad Instruction with error array out of range?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I found an error saying `"Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"` which the console is outputting Array index out of range, what I believe as to why its giving the out of range error is because in the following code, the resultsProfileName is checked to be nil, and the array is counting the nil, causing it to be out of range.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username != '"+userName+"'")
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User", predicate: predicate)
    var objects = query.findObjects()


    for object in objects! {


        self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object.username!!)

        if let profileUsername = object["profileName"] as? String
        {
        self.resultsProfileNameArray.append(profileUsername)
        }
        if let profileUserpictures = object["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
        self.resultsImageFiles.append(profileUserpictures)
        }

        self.resultsTable.reloadData()

    }
}
```

[image: Crash]

Comment: You're getting that error because `indexPath.row` isn't a valid index for `resultsProfileNameArray`. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560147/fatal-error-array-index-out-of-range-in-swift-xcode6

Comment: @ABakerSmith How is indexPath.row not a valid index for resultsProfileNameArray, indexPath is created in the func tableView

Comment: In the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you're setting the number of rows to be `resultsUsernameArray.count`; which I suspect has more elements than `resultsProfileNameArray`.

Comment: @ABakerSmith  I just created a check for the resultsProfileUsernameArray to check if its nil or not, do you know how to create a check for the resultsUsernameArray, because i just edited it with                                           `if let resultUsername = object.username { self.resultsUsernameArray.append(resultUsername!)      }` and it still gives out the same error